# use dialogflow webhooks from alexa

Tags: webhooks, alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es

I have developed a complex dialogflow bot, which uses complex dialogs to get data from user and then store it in database. And then give responses to users by querying db.

Can i use the same logic/webhooks/code to call from alexa skill? I don't want to write such a complex logic again for alexa skill.

What I want is whenever an alexa intent is called by user, i want  to transfer that intent to my dialogflow webhook to handle it. Is it possible? If so then can you please provide any documentation/examples/tutorials ets.

My dialogflow model consists of 4 slot types:

1. Date
2. Number
3. any
4. some custom slots

Answer (score 2):

I am certain this is not possible straight away as the REST API of Dialogflow will be different from that of Alexa. Also, Alexa is not fully supported for integration in Dialogflow like Facebook or Slack. If your code is well written and business logic is separate from the platform/request/response mapping then you will be able to use the same business logic in your Alexa webhook code. You just need to write the code for consuming the REST API of Alexa in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. While Dialogflow and Alexa have different webhook JSON formats, fundamentally they both do the same thing. You will need to handle parsing the JSON to get what you need, and then formatting the response, so each uses their particular format - but the logic that you are using should still be sound and available to both.

Dialogflow lets you [export the model into an Alexa compatible format](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations#amazon_alexa_and_microsoft_cortana) that you can paste into the Alexa Skills Kit. This helps at least a bit.